# simultaneous access to a utility function in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have a simple utility function defined on an object. Like the one below, it reads an immutable data structure from the object. Can many threads, or in this case many Akka actors, call this method simultaneously?

```
object Util {
  private val names = Set("alice", "bob")

  def isName(s: String) = names.contains(s.toLowerCase)
}
```

Comment: Yes. _(more characters so I can comment)_

Comment: What do you mean by "can many threads call this method"? Are they allowed to do it? Or, will it cause any issue if they do it?

Comment: @GaëlJ my question is if the access can be truly simultaneous. But I see now that as long as I don't add any concurrency control such as a mutex or semaphore, it can be.